# Is there any Python async library available for Google Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using Google Cloud Bigtable and looks like Google officially doesn't support async way of inserting data into Bigtable.

somethings like `await client.mutate([data])`

Comment: Please specify your problem, what is your question?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @quent

Simple, is there any python async library for Bigtable :)

SolomonDuskis I have a situation where I have to write data into BigTable asynchronously, how will I do it in Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar request from January 2018 (See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4713)).

For some context, this feature is generally used for higher throughput in batch jobs, and some "fire-and-forget" cases.  Integration with [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) would benefit from this feature.

Unfortunately, this type of implementation is tricky, and other issues had to be dealt with first.  The Cloud Bigtable Python client recently achieved Beta status, which means that the team can start working on more complex functionality like async writes.

I would suggest either commenting on the original [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4713) if your use case is similar, or creating a new [feature request](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/new/choose) that better matches with your use case.